# Images Not Rendering from Amazon S3 Bucket

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3

***Update***

Ok so I decided to test a bare minimum build for fetching and rendering images in the component. Images are being rendered on the page here qnd quickly as expected which tells me the issue is with the fetching, url construction, or rendering code rather than aws/amplify configuration.

```
//SetsTest.js

import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { View, Image, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from "react-native";
import { Storage } from "aws-amplify";

export default function Sets_Dev() {
  const [imageUrls, setImageUrls] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchFirstTwoImages = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await Storage.list("pkmn_set_logos_eng/", {
          maxKeys: 3, // Fetching 3 because the first one might be the directory itself
        });

        console.log("S3 Response:", response);

        if (!response.results || response.results.length === 0) {
          console.error("No items returned from S3.");
          return;
        }

        // Filter out the directory key and then map to get the URLs
        const validResults = response.results.filter(
          (item) => item.key !== "pkmn_set_logos_eng/"
        );

        const urls = await Promise.all(
          validResults.map((item) => Storage.get(item.key, { level: "public" }))
        );

        setImageUrls(urls);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Failed to fetch images from S3:", error);
      }
    };

    fetchFirstTwoImages();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {imageUrls.map((url, index) => (
        <Image
          key={index}
          source={{ uri: url }}
          style={styles.image}
          resizeMode="contain"
        />
      ))}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    flexDirection: "row",
    padding: 10,
  },
  image: {
    width: Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.45,
    height: Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.45,
    margin: 5,
  },
});
```

***Main***

I'm in the process of building a react-native Mobile Application. I have a component/screen that is supposed to render 21 images at a time into 2 columns with pagination from S3 upon Navigation.

**I cannot for the life of me figure out why Images are rendering extremely slowly (>10 minutes) on the screen.*** All of the images in the bucket are between 20 - 600kbs in size so I don't think size is the issue. There are about 150 images in the bucket but I'm paginating 21 at a time. Decreasing/Increasing the page size isn't changing the time to render on the screen.

I believe my bucket's permissions and Amplify are set up correctly to be able to perform this operation because I can paste the object URL into my browser and see the image, I am not proficient so its possible Im wrong.

I believe the S3 buckets permissions and Amplify are configured properly because I am able to paste the object URL into my browser and view the image.

Here is my code:

```
//Sets.js

import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import colors from "./colors";
import {
  FlatList,
  View,
  Text,
  Dimensions,
  StyleSheet,
  ActivityIndicator,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TextInput,
  Image,
} from "react-native";
import { Storage } from "aws-amplify";

const { width } = Dimensions.get("window");
const PAGE_SIZE = 21; // Updated the page size
const CONTAINER_PADDING = 20;
const CONTAINER_WIDTH = (width - 40 - CONTAINER_PADDING * 2) / 2;

export default function Sets({ navigation }) {
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
  const [nextToken, setNextToken] = useState(undefined);
  const [hasNextPage, setHasNextPage] = useState(true);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState("");

  const fetchImages = async () => {
    if (!hasNextPage || isLoading) return;
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await Storage.list("pkmn_set_logos_eng/", {
        pageSize: PAGE_SIZE,
        nextToken: nextToken,
      });

      if (response && response.results && Array.isArray(response.results)) {
        const filteredImages = response.results.filter(
          (item) => item.key !== "pkmn_set_logos_eng/" && !item.key.endsWith("/")
        );

        const imageURLs = await Promise.all(
          filteredImages.map(async (item) => {
            const setId = item.key.split("/")[1].split(".")[0];
            const imageUrl = await Storage.get(item.key, { level: "public" });
            return { setId, imageUrl };
          })
        );

        const setTotals = await Promise.all(
          imageURLs.map((image) => fetchSetTotal(image.setId))
        );

        imageURLs.forEach((image, index) => {
          image.setTotal = setTotals[index];
        });

        setImages((prevImages) => [...prevImages, ...imageURLs]);
        setIsLoading(false);
        setNextToken(response.nextToken);
        setHasNextPage(!!response.nextToken);
      } else {
        throw new Error("Unexpected response format from Storage.list");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      setIsLoading(false);
      setHasNextPage(false);
    }
  };

  const fetchSetTotal = async (setId) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `http://MyIp:3000/get-set-total/${setId}`
      );
      if (!response.ok) return null;
      return await response.json();
    } catch (error) {
      return null;
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchImages();
  }, []);

  const renderImageItem = ({ item }) => (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.imageContainer}
      onPress={() => {
        navigation.navigate("SetClickScreen", {
          setId: item.setId,
          imageUrl: item.imageUrl,
          setTotal: item.setTotal,
        });
      }}
    >
      <View style={styles.whiteContainer}>
        <Image
          source={{ uri: item.imageUrl }}
          style={styles.image}
          resizeMode="contain"
        />
      </View>
      <Text style={styles.placeholderText}>{`0/${item.setTotal}`}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.placeholderText}>Set Value: $0.00</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );

  const renderFooter = () =>
    isLoading && (
      <View style={styles.loadingContainer}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="small" color="gray" />
      </View>
    );
```

```
return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: colors.light }}>
      <FlatList
        data={images}
        renderItem={renderImageItem}
        keyExtractor={(_, index) => index.toString()}
        numColumns={2}
        contentContainerStyle={styles.container}
        onEndReached={fetchImages}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
        ListHeaderComponent={
          <View style={styles.searchAndButtonsContainer}>
            <View style={styles.searchContainer}>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.searchBar}
                onChangeText={setSearchText}
                value={searchText}
                placeholder="Search for a set..."
                placeholderTextColor="gray"
              />
            </View>
          </View>
        }
        ListFooterComponent={renderFooter}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    padding: 5 + CONTAINER_PADDING,
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: colors.light,
  },
  imageContainer: {
    width: CONTAINER_WIDTH,
    height: CONTAINER_WIDTH + 40,
    padding: 5,
    marginBottom: -15,
    marginTop: 45,
    marginLeft: CONTAINER_PADDING / 2,
    marginRight: CONTAINER_PADDING / 2,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  whiteContainer: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "70%",
    borderRadius: 15,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: colors.primary,
  },
  image: {
    width: "90%",
    height: "90%",
  },
  placeholderText: {
    marginTop: 5,
    color: colors.primary,
  },
  searchAndButtonsContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    paddingHorizontal: 8,
    marginTop: 0,
  },
  searchContainer: {
    width: width * 0.8 - 10,
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    height: 38,
    borderColor: "gray",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 5,
    paddingHorizontal: 8,
    marginRight: 10,
  },
  searchBar: {
    flex: 1,
    height: 38,
    color: colors.primary,
  },
});
```

```
//App.js

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Amplify, Storage } from "aws-amplify";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import AppNavigator from "./AppNavigator";
import LoadingScreen from "./LoadingScreen";
import awsmobile from "./src/aws-exports";

Amplify.configure(awsmobile),
  {
    Auth: {
      identityPoolId: IDENTITYPOOLID,
      region: "us-east-2",
    },
    Storage: {
      AWSS3: {
        bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
        region: "us-east-2",
        level: "public",
      },
    },
  };

Storage.configure({
  customPrefix: {
    public: "",
  },
});

function AppComponent() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  // Simulate loading
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }, 3000); // 3-second delay
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <LoadingScreen />;
  }
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <AppNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default AppComponent;
```

Here is the bucket policy for the bucket im fetching from

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::FakeBucketARN/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Did you set proper content-type for them in S3?

Comment: all of the objects in the bucket and folder im trying to render images from are .png files.

Comment: Ok, so did you setup set proper content-type for them in S3? Each object should have proper content-type. For png it is `image/png`.

Comment: Yes, I just checked the metadata the value for the content types are image/png

Comment: Is your bucket public?

Comment: Yes the bucket is public.

Comment: Also why Amplify.configure(awsmobile), Has a comma after it? Is that a typo?

Comment: I replaced the s3 fetch with a placeholder image to load each container in the two columns, everything worked as expected. I cant determine whether or not my issue is the way aws/amplify is configured for my project or if the issue is related to the way Im fetching objects from the bucket, constructing image URLS from the objects and then rendering them in the containers.

Comment: It seems like your fetchImages function has a logic error. You're checking if response is an array, but according to the AWS Amplify documentation, the Storage.list method returns an object, not an array. So, you should modify your fetchImages method.

Comment: I just updated the post to include my full refactored code with the return statement and stylesheet

Comment: Still have not found a solution. I'm thinking that there is some sort of extremely inefficient loop occurring that is slowing down the processing.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to everyone who ended up helping. It turns out there was simply an error in the address I was using to fetch a feature in the component from a Mysql table. Because the rendering of the images was reliant upon the endpoint request it was causing huge delays in my image rendering.